# Как в FastReport привязать masterData вертикального бэнда к masterData обыкновенного бэнда?

Tags: delphi, fastreport

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Количество дат и материалов изменяемое.

Выборка вертикального бэнда:

```
select m.* 
from balance b
left join materials m on m.id = b.material_id
```

Выборка горизонтального бэнда:

```
select b.date,b.price,b.amount, ... ,m.id 
from balance b
left join materials m on m.id = b.material_id
```

запросы сильно упрощены, но суть (как мне кажется) осталась.

Comment: Добавьте больше подробностей, приведите пример выдачи которая должна получится.

Comment: @Kromster прошу прощения, вопрос дополнен!

Comment: Может быть имеет смысл использовать кросс-отчет? В документации к FR довольно доступно описано как его использовать.

Comment: @ЕвгенийАлександров, возможно и имеет смысл, да загвоздка в том, что в моей версии FR кросс отчеты вырезаны(. Обрезанный FR поставлялся с RadStudio. А ломаный на 10.1 Berlin найти не удалось(

Comment: Я не много работал, с FR, но версия, которая поставляется с Rad Studio, довольно сильно порезана, а руководство не захотело покупать лицензию. Поэтому пришлось использовать DevExpress и их PivotGrid совместно с экспортом в Excel и Printing System:) Может быть это поможет.

Comment: @ЕвгенийАлександров Вот же ирония судьбы) Мне и DevExpress'om запретили пользоваться потому как пользователь привык к старому интерфейсу(Дико звучит но все же). Хотя использовать PivotGrid никто не запрещает потому как отчеты все же делать нужно) Если ничего не придумаю с FR придется перейти на PivotGrid

Comment: У DevExpress можно отключить поддержку скинов и тогда они будут выглядеть как "старые" :)))